# Connecting to MongoDB using Spring Repository

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/ - The example does not show connecting to Mongo DB usage.

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.mongo-xml-config

Answer (score 1):

default spring data mongo db is connect your localhost  if you not declare any connfiguration properties in `applicaiton.properties` file

for example

launch mongodb server with `mongod` command and after launch your application and make any `CRUD` operation see log in your command prompt

if your application need special server uri or any configuration properties

add `application.properties` file this properties and configure

for example

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://user:secret@mongo1.example.com:12345,mongo2.example.com:23456/test
```

this configure your uri with colleciton names

and also declare host and port with this

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=mongoserver
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
```

and also more properties  knowledges(for example: username and password settings) here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

connecting features here : 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-connecting-to-mongodb